# Use update or insert trigger to subscribe report using SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, triggers, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

[Use Database Insert Trigger to Publish Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388999/use-database-insert-trigger-to-publish-reports/21303127#21303127)

I know this is quiet old post... but even I have one question quiet same like above situation.

When I create trigger to execute msdb.dbo.sp_start_job procedure, what parameters I need to pass to it?? can I pass any Id of Loan(as my report is related to Loans) so that i can send mail for that loan number only????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this??